# Fiberglass insulation above grade in basement

Tags: insulation, basement, vapor-barrier, fiberglass

We have an unfinished basement that we want to finish. The walls are bare concrete and there is no subfloor. In the exterior, it seems there is a vapor barrier (we have the tar marks on the wall) . We are thinking about rigid foam on the concrete walls, then studs then drywall. We will put subfloor and some insulation on the floor, so we will leave the basement ceiling unfinished for a more industrial look. However, in the basement, on the superior edge of the concrete, right under what would be the OSB subfloor of the top floor, there is fiberglass (uncovered, nothing behind it). I think it is on the above grade section. [image: fiberglass basement insulation] Is that alright? Should we rip off the fiberglass and fill with spray foam and then cover with sections of drywall? Can we cover that section of fiberglass with a moisture barrier and then put drywall on top?

*Note: I live in Michigan, USDA zones 5b/6a (borderline). Low temp in winter, lots of snow; hot, humid summers. Also, our home is on a hill. The section in the picture is the deepest in the house (below grade section starts under those little windows) . In other parts, the above grade section may start from deeper in the ground than in the picture.

Comment: The International Residential Code is typically your building code anywhere in the US. It prescribes 7'-0" minimum ceiling heights for habitable spaces (hallways, sleeping rooms, and kitchens) and 6'-8" ceiling heights for laundry areas and bathrooms. Beams (not joists) and HVAC ducts can hang as low as 6'-4". See [IRC R305](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2015/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2015_Pt03_Ch03_SecR305).

Comment: Insulation details within wall assemblies vary with local climate. You'll need to describe your local climate to get good advice. In my region we have winters with high relative humidity and summers with low relative humidity, so our vapor barrier goes on the inside. This prevents indoor humidity during the winter from reaching the outer wall where it would condense. During the summer there's no humidity from outside to condense on the cool air conditioned inside surface of the vapor barrier.

Comment: Thanks! I added that info!

Comment: Could you better explain the "black marks on the wall"? Are you talking about some kind of tar sealant on the exterior side of the concrete? Is there already a vapor barrier between the fiberglass insulation and the exterior wall?

Comment: Hi! Yes, tar sealant on the exterior of the concrete. We have not seen anything between the fiberglass insulation and the exterior wall.

Comment: Fiberglass is good stuff. Why switch to foam? Foam in small quantities (fill little holes) is Great Stuff. But in large quantities is is [a huge fire hazard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdItsso3ur0).